# How to sort string in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I want to get a result sorted by name(string), and this is what I do:

1.create index named as metadata
PUT http://IP:9200/metadata/
2. create  type name as objects
POST http://ip:9200/metadata/objects

```
{
"mappings":{
    "objects":{
        "properties":{
            "name":{
                "type":"string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "version":{
                "type":"integer"
            },
            "size":{
                "type":"integer"
            },
            "hash":{
                "type":"string"
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

}

3. insert data

POST http://ip:9200/metadata/objects/test3_1?op_type=create

```
{
  "name":"test3",
  "version":1,
   "size":13,
   "hash":"2oUvHeq7jQ27Va2y/usI1kSX4cETY9LuevZU9RT+Fuc="
}
```

4. get result sorted by name

GET http://101.43.155.248:9200/metadata//_search?sort=name,version

and the error is

Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [name] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to use the `.keyword` for your sort field, if it's created dynamically or define additional field as `.keyword` on which you need sorting.

As you created index mapping manually, you need to add the `.keyword` manually on the `name` field, on the `price` there is no issue as on numeric field it works.

Comment: your answer helps me to solve my problem. thank u